# How can I prepopulate the structure of a complex nested form on the Create button in a List view in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin, react-final-form

The `List` View of react-admin provides a "create (new record)" button out of the box when I specify a `Create` view in the `Resource`.

Since my record structure is nested up to three levels, containing objects with objects with arrays a.s.o., starting with an empty record (just `{}`) leads to a bunch of "undefined" errors in the validation function and when I test certain values with a `FormDataConsumer` to fold/unfold parts of the form based on other values.

I want my `Create` view to always start with a predefined record structure. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you need default values for create form.

**Documentation**: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#default-values

```
const postDefaultValue = { created_at: new Date(), nb_views: 0 };
export const PostCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm initialValues={postDefaultValue}>
            <TextInput source="title" />
            <RichTextInput source="body" />
            <NumberInput source="nb_views" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

Comment: thanks!, I did not think of an empty structure as "default values" for fields. The dcoumentation is not very detailled.

The documentation link is:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#default-values

Comment: thanks, the link in the post fixed, wrong copy, thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten all the nested structure, and restore the input data back to the nested structure before submission. This document may help you: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#altering-the-form-values-before-submitting

Comment: theoretically yes, but that would be neither elegant not worth the effort.

Comment: I agree. Using default-value is better.